# Is it possible to prevent two processes writing to the same cache item?

Tags: azure, redis, azureservicebus

I would like to do something similar to described in this article
http://vunvulearadu.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/activeactive-mechanism-over-azure.html  where when one of my instances picks up a service bus message from the primary it adds an item to the redis cache. Then if another instance was processing a copy of the message on the secondary it can first check to see if that message has already been handled and ignore it if so.

The problem, seems to me that if both instances attempt to process the message (one from primary, one from secondary) at the same time then it is possible that  they both read from cache and find nothing and then write to cache at the same time. So my question is, what happens if they both write to cache at the same time. Ideally I want one to fail, so that it can assume that another instance is processing the message. Is that possible though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [SETNX](http://redis.io/commands/setnx) (or MSETNX or HSETNX, depending of the structure of the data you want to store) feature of REDIS.
It will write the value if and only if it is not already set.
As REDIS is monothread, it will guarantee you that only the first instance will succeed - as long as you use the same key for the data.

Comment: should I be looking at Redlock ?

Comment: If my understanding of your problem is correct, you don't. Redlock provides a way to acquire a lock in a reliable way, with several Redis instances. It offers high availabilty. It is not designed to store data in cache.